# I want to increment "B101" this id to "B102" , how can i use spillt method to do that?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating windows from application, if i click the insert button insert id want to increment by one, but here, i used int id with the string, How can i do that in simple way?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            viewPanel("panel3");
            List<String> idList= new List<String>();
            foreach (Item i in itemList)
                idList.Add(i.ItemId);
            idList.Sort();

            textBox2.Text = "" + (idList[idList.Count - 1] + 1);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us code and your attempt? where did you stuck?

Comment: is there any logic behind alphanumeric value ?

Comment: Is (only) the first character always non-numeric, while the rest is? Is the numeric part always three characters? What about `99`? Would that be `B99` or `B099`? And what should happen after `B999`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general case, you can extract `"101"`, `Parse` it to `int`, increment it and put it back as a `String`. For instance *regular expressions* code

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 string source = "B101";

 // Increments each number within the string
 //   B101   -> B102
 //   A456xC -> A457xC
 //   PQ_001 -> PQ_002
 string result = Regex.Replace(
    source, 
   "[0-9]+", 
    m => (long.Parse(m.Value) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(m.Length, '0'));
```